# Aligning geotiff file with raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, alignment

i am having some trouble and i could use some help. I downloaded a Geotiff file on WGS84 for the area that i am working for and i would like to clip it so it fits the outline of my map (red polygon).

All the layers of my map are set on Greek Grid. I use the Project tool from arc toolbox (Projections and Transformations-Raster) and i create a new shapefile with GreekGrid as spacial reference. Then i clip my file with Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> clip.

This is the result i am getting. The red box is the outline of my map and it doesn't align with my file.

Am i doing something wrong? Someone suggested to use the extract by mask by mask tool because but i am having odd results with this tool. I post screen shot of the result below below. The first on is with using the clip tool, and the second with using the extract by mask tool.

[image: Using the clip tool]
[image: Using the extract by mask tool]

Comment: Did you set a geographic/datum transformation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the coordinate system. When using the clip tool to "crop"  raster with a polygon that is not perfectly aligned with pixels use the option to clip to geometry or something like that (can't remember exacly). Otherwise the result is cliped to the bounding box of geometry: the result you got from the tool.